# git merge, git rebase none seems to work, should I delete my github fork and refork from the upstream master?

Tags: git, github, merge, fork, rebase

I have to confess my github sins. 
4 month ago, I forked a upstream repo, without knowing much of git and pull request, i did some work on master branch locally, later on I realized the mistake, created a new branch, and squashed the changes to one and successfully send a PR later from that branch. the PR is accepted, and I moved on.

Now I need to submit another PR. But my master branch is so messed up, when I do merge, or rebase, there are so many mistakes. I probably committed a few more sins this morning.

I have been battling this for the whole morning now. so it comes to the point that I want a clean start.

Can I delete the github fork and refork from the upstream master? What are the correct steps?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do a `reset --hard` of your master on the upstream master, then a `push --force` on your fork to reset it like the original master.